# How to resolve stack size exceeded errror?

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, validation

Please help me !

All of sudden, i'm facing a strange error on console saying

```
 Maximum call stack size exceededreplace @ (program):163ga @ ajax_1.11.3.js:2ga.matches @ ajax_1.11.3.js:2m.filter @ ajax_1.11.3.js:2w @ ajax_1.11.3.js:2m.fn.extend.is @ ajax_1.11.3.js:2FormValidation.Base._getMessageContainer @ formValidation.min.js:10FormValidation.Base._getMessageContainer @ formValidation.min.js:10FormValidation.Base._getMessageContainer @ formValidation.min.js:10FormValidation.Base._getMessageContainer @ formValidation.min.js:10
```

After including these bootstrap form validation files under `body` tag

```
    <script src="js/ajax_1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/formValidation.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/formValidation_bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/oneWay_validation.js"></script>
```

This is the line 10 at formValidation.min.js

```
if(window.FormValidation={AddOn:{},Framework:{},I18n:{},Validator:`{}},"undefined"==typeof jQuery)throw new Error("FormValidation requires jQuery");!function(a){var b=a.fn.jquery.split(" ")[0].split(".");if(+b[0]<2&&+b[1]<9||1===+b[0]&&9===+b[1]&&+b[2]<1)throw new Error("FormValidation requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher")}(jQuery),function(a){FormValidation.Base=function(b,c,d){this.$form=a(b),this.options=a.extend({},a.fn.formValidation.DEFAULT_OPTIONS,c),this._namespace=d||"fv",this.$invalidFields=a([]),this.$submitButton=null`
```

Comment: Try the non-minified version...

Comment: sorry ?
Which version and from where i can get that ?

Comment: Where did you get the `formValidation.min.js` from?

Comment: @Tracker1
 It was online cdns link, i copied it to my directory and now calling it from there.
In my last project it's working perfect !
But now it's get starting problem :(

Comment: Then go to where you got it, and get the one without the .min ... there is probably a header in your .min.js that has the version, just get the same one without the .min

Comment: How did you save it locally?  your editor may have added extra line-feeds or spacing, etc...

Comment: Form here i copied the cdns for form alidation
http://formvalidation.io/getting-started/

Comment: It says right there on the page, that the package should have both the minified and the not minified version.. the one without the .min in the name.

Comment: @Tracker1
Simply i just visit the link i found there and copied the code and saved into my local directory

Comment: If you don't care about solving your problem, but only having no Errors, do : `Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;` I'm saying this because the title seems to only care about that

Comment: Look, I'm sorry, but I'm not paid tech support... if you can't figure out how to get the `formValidation.js` (note, no `.min.`) them I'm afraid I don't even know where to start to help you.  I don't mean to be snarky, but this is really basic stuff.

Comment: @Tracker1
Can you please tell me once that according to you, i should include formValidation.js not min.js. Yeaah ?
And it it's so then why it's working perfectly in my previous project yet

Comment: I cannot help you.  I didn't write formValidation, and I'm not paid for this... I had some down time, and am trying to be nice.

Comment: @Tracker1
Means if are not getting paid so you never help others.
Alright !
Thanks for your time :)

Comment: No, but I expect *YOU* the one seeking help to put a minimal amount of effort towards helping yourself, which you are clearly either unable to do, or refuse to do.  How do you expect me to know what version to use, what version you are using, or where to look?  Did you look in the file itself, is there a header with which version and who wrote it?

Comment: @Tracker1
Actually i'm the new on javascript and don't knows the deep knowledge. Anyhow, i'm trying to find out solution .

Comment: I'm sorry that it's difficult for you... I suggest you use the formValidation.js that came with formValidation.min.js and use that instead... The site you linked to apparently has both.

http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/add-breakpoints

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KbEx0s06VLs

Comment: @Tracker1
Thanks for your suggestion but i didn't find any file there without .min.

Comment: Is there a comment/license at the top of formValidation.min.js???  That should lead you to where to go... you can debug, but without the unminified versions, or source maps, it will be painful...

Comment: I'm assuming you paid for it via formvalidation.io, where you linked to?  Should look to them for support... if you have a teacher/mentor/coworker you can ask, would go there too... This is really better for a clear question, with a firm answer, you need help troubleshooting to get to that point.

Comment: @Tracker1
My question was very clear but i don't know what did you find difficulty to understand.
....................
Anyhow, i have resolved my issue after spending whole night....
And yes, what you had said , that for me to solve this problem is very difficult !!! ..
I want to let you know that nothing is easy and possible in this world and even in programming even html..... If you don't understand the question and have answer accordingly then please never demotivate others by saying such sentences.
...
Anyhow, for you plugin suggestion, i am thankful to you !